# How to commit in batches using OGR in Python

Tags: python, ogr, batch

When working with OGR in Python you have to set your `target_layer` and `target_datasource` to `None` in order to commit the features to the database. But I'm handling a large dataset of 2,7 million records. And I would like to commit features in batches. How would you achieve this?

Do I have to create a new `target_datasource` thus a fresh connection for each batch?

Comment: Study how ogr2ogr does that when `-gt` is used https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [start and commit transaction](https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc54_dataset_transactions.html) in a layer, like this:

```
target_layer.StartTransaction()

*...do your stuff...*

target_layer.CommitTransaction()
```

[here's a example](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#create-a-postgis-table-from-wkt)